# How to obtain the bibtex item for a question with a program?

Tags: support, citations

### Background

The [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org/) project encourages contributors to provide references for combinatorial statistics.

I am currently redesigning the way such references are processed.  In future, a contributor should only type something like [[arxiv:1234.5678]] or [[MO168885]], without providing any further information.  The program then will fetch author and title from the various websites.  This was (relatively) easy for the arXiv, but for mathoverflow citations (which occur a lot, by nature of the site), I'm hitting a problem:

### Question

Which request should my program send to mathoverflow.net to get the bibtex, which is so well hidden behind the share button.

Rephrased: what I'm after is something analogous to a link like:

http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2011arXiv1111.3349P&data_type=BIBTEX

which serves the bibtex for arXiv articles.

Comment: Possibly it would have been better to ask this at http://meta.stackexchange.com.  Is it possible to migrate the question, or should I simply ask there, too?

Comment: It would be possible to migrate it (via flagging for moderators), but if you decide to ask it there I'd just do the simple thing and re-ask (and  delete this one, or just add links).  I agree you might get an answer there more easily, however I recommend to explain very clearly what you are taking about and in particular to stress that this feature exists on MO and some other (science) sites, yet not everywhere. (Else the SO-crowd could be confused as there and on plenty other sites the feature does not exist.)

Comment: There is something related we're looking into right now. In a plausible future, we may be able to generate DOIs for archived questions. It will then be easy to generate the bibtex you want via [DOI content negotiation](http://www.crosscite.org/cn/). Also check out the [answers here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1631/formatting-a-citation-to-a-mathoverflow-answer/1655#1655) to resolve issues with the bibtex currently generated by the cite button.

Comment: This question was cross-posted, and answered, at both [Meta Stack Exchange (256587)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256587/how-to-obtain-the-bibtex-item-for-a-question-with-a-program-or-http-request) and [Stack Apps (6331)](http://stackapps.com/questions/6331/how-to-obtain-the-bibtex-item-for-a-question-with-a-program-or-http-request).

Comment: @BrockAdams did you want to expand this comment into an answer?

Comment: @DavidRoberts, go ahead if you want to.  It seems wasteful to me to have it asked and answered in 3 different places. I was wondering if some closing/migration might occur.

Comment: @MartinRubey you can accept the answer here, for the sake of preventing the system complaining.

Comment: @BrockAdams only pointing people to the other answer, for the sake of closing this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brock Adams mentioned in the comments, this is asked and answered at: [How to obtain the bibtex item for a question with a program or http request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256587/how-to-obtain-the-bibtex-item-for-a-question-with-a-program-or-http-request)