# referencing a MO reply

Tags: discussion, citations

In a book or article, how should I reference a helpful reply on mathoverflow? Can I give the web reference to the question? If so, in what form? I would rather do this than the catch all `personal communication', which is never very helpful and also does not acknowledge the role of mathoverflow itself.

Comment: Are you happy with the results of the 'cite' button that appears below the post?  There's also the 'share' functionality for linking.

Comment: See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1631/formatting-a-citation-to-a-mathoverflow-answer (note that the cite-link moved though) More generally see the questions tagged [meta-tag:citations].

Comment: Note that the share-features creates a personalized link that contains your userID; for citations you might want to omit this last bit.

Comment: @quid: And miss the opportunity for a Publicist badge earned through Annals of Mathematics? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: well, I said "might." :-) Mainly I said it as some claimed to find this feature borderline dangerous. So I felt like issuing a warning.

Comment: OK, I see that there was an answer - thanks for pointing it out.